# Using jQuery to only show one of a pair of elements

Tags: jquery

I have a number of message elements that come in pairs: If element A1 is shown, then A2 should be hidden, same for B1/B2, C1/C2, and so on.  I have the jQuery code working, but it gets verbose:

```
if (conditionA) {
    $("#a1").show();
    $("#a2").hide();
else {
    $("#a1").hide();
    $("#a2").show();
}

if (conditionB) {
    $("#b1").show();
    $("#b2").hide();
else {
    $("#b1").hide();
    $("#b2").show();
}

//etc...
```

This seems cumbersome and mind-numbing.  Is there a better way to encapsulate the notion that these elements are paired and should show/hide opposite each other?  I've looked at toggle, but that isn't right.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? May be there is a way to organize the HTML to reduce this repetitive code.

Comment: @Ned, just a fyi, but toggle also has the ability to toggle between two functions, keeping state internally. e.g. $("#id").toggle(function() { alert("hi"); }, function() { alert("bye"); });  I felt remiss in not mentioning this so that you have more information going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

I organized the HTML to have the pair of elements paired under a new parent for naming purposes:

```
<p id="first_flap"><span class="flap">MsgA1</span><span class="flap">MsgA2</span></p>
<p id="second_flap"><span class="flap">MsgB1</span><span class="flap">MsgB2</span></p>
```

Each of the pair has class "flap" on it.  Then I can write a function:

```
function flip_flap(sel, cond) {
    /* Find sel, then show flaps within it according to cond. */
    var flaps = jQuery(sel + ">.flap");
    var f0 = jQuery(flaps[0]);
    (cond ? f0.show() : f0.hide());
    var f1 = jQuery(flaps[1]);
    (cond ? f1.hide() : f1.show());
}
```

I liked the idea of using toggle(), but unfortunately, it doesn't work for inline elements, only block level, and I needed to use spans.

Then I can replace my original Javascript with:

```
flip_flap("#first_flap", conditionA);
flip_flap("#second_flap", conditionB);
```

Much more concise!  Thanks.

Comment: `toggle` routes to `hide` and `show`, which handle both block and inline elements (at least in 1.3.2). What version are you using where you cannot toggle inline elements?

Answer (score 3):

Actually `toggle` *can* help you here, if you make use of the optional [`switch`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle#switch) parameter.

```
$("#a1").toggle(conditionA);
$("#a2").toggle(!conditionA);

$("#b1").toggle(conditionB);
$("#b2").toggle(!conditionB);
```

Comment: Ah! I had misunderstood what the parameter to toggle meant.

Comment: The `!`'s should be reversed there. Toggle *hides* the element if the switch is `true`, not the other way around.

Comment: My apologies, perhaps I should have checked the documentation myself! Fixed.

Comment: After using this functionality myself in one of my own projects, it seems the jQuery documentation is incorrect on this matter and toggle *shows* the element if switch is `true`.

I have reverted my changes to the comment and filed a bug report: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5153

Answer (score 0):

I would organize your html so that you could use siblings() and toggle().

Comment: Can you show an example? Keep in mind, I don't want to necessarily change the state of the divs at all: my understanding of toggle was that it examined the current state, and flipped between hide and show.  I might run through my code and the conditions are all the same as last time, and nothing is changed.